# Decoding Apache Kafka Logs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have recently started studying Apache Kafka.
I configured zookeeper , Also configured Kafka instance(broker).
Everything is working fine.
Yesterday i sent lot of messages using producer(using default partition) and consumed them .This activity created lot of log folders with format

Topic-Name Partition-Number
eg:- Ajinkya-0 , Ajinkya-10 , Ajinkya-12 etc...

Today when i restarted Apache Kafka , i got lot of logs

```
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,917] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-39, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,917] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-39, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,918] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-39, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 2 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,919] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Recovering unflushed segment 0 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,919] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,920] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,920] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 1 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,922] INFO [Log partition=Ajinkya-74, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Recovering unflushed segment 0 (kafka.log.Log)
```

Why do i see logs as

```
Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)    
 Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 1 ms (kafka.log.Log)
```

Since message has already been consumed ,  **why do i still see loading logs** ?
Also i saw loading logs for all partitions i.e 50 partitions
As no of partitions will increase , no of logs will also increase .

Comment: The consumer offsets topic by default starts with 50 partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics).

Kafka is not like traditional messaging middleware (JMS, RabbitMQ etc).

Records are retained in the logs for 7 days (by default). See `log.retention.hours` and `log.retention.minutes`. Consumers can "rewind" back as far as the retention period.

I removed the [spring-kafka](/questions/tagged/spring-kafka) tag since this question has nothing at all to do with Spring.

Comment: Hi Gary ,Sorry  i included spring-kafka tag but i have currently implemented apache kafka in plain Java , but my company's requirement is doing it in Spring .   Also i have only found examples of Apache Kafka with Spring Boot , can you tell me where can i find examples using simple Spring MVC

Comment: There are no requirements to use boot; it just makes your life easier since it wires up the required infrastructure beans for you (producer/consumer factories etc). See the [quick start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_introduction.html#quick-tour).